# Selected video from gallery is mirroed/flipped ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, video-player

I have used SCPlayer from SCrecorder to play a video, Whenever I captured video from camera then it works fine but if I used Video from gallery then It will be Flipped Please check below image

**Original Video Image**
[image: **Original Video Image**]

**Flipped Video Image**
[image: **Flipped Video Image**]

I have used following code :

```
var player: SCPlayer?
var session = SCRecordSession()

    player?.setItemBy(session.assetRepresentingSegments())
    player?.autoRotate = true
    if seekTime != nil {
        player?.seek(to: seekTime!)
    }
    player?.play()
```

How can I stop this flipping, Please help!